# Plesk Panel default ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, https, centos6, plesk

This problem is driving me mad but hopefully to you people it may be simple.
This is what I have done:-

- Created a new (self-signed) SSL certificate in Plesk 12 to secure the panel.
- Set it to use this as the panel certificate.
- Changed the ip address to use this new certificate in Tools/IP Addresses

I have checked the sites ssl certificate on numerous online    checkers and they all report the certificate is fine (although it being self-signed).

But whenever I browse to the panel I still get 'Your connection is not private'
[image: Google Chrome connection not private]

The trouble is then that the PEM encoded chain, which I believe to be the certificate it's using, is not the self-signed certificate I created. Then after a certain period of time, approx 5 mins, even when I'm still using the admin it will go to 'Your connection is not private' again and show a different PEM encoded chain.

Please could someone help as this drives me crazy when I'm using Plesk.
The sever is running CentOS 6.6 and the servers default address is sris1.co.uk

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are accessing both https://sris1.co.uk and https://www.sris1.co.uk, while certificate is issues for www. domain, and it's understandably failing when you access just sris1.co.uk, and browser thinks, that you are being tricked, since cert is issued for different site.

I've never met such problems in Plesk, so, this is only thing, that I can guess from provided information.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it doesn't matter which domain name I use with or without the www. It still uses a random ssl certificate.